# Can Meteor run with a Microsoft back end (ie EF and ASP.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, meteor

Perhaps like some of you, I am inundated by the number of JavaScript MV* out there. When I thought I was going KO, I found Backbone, then Ember.

**I recently saw some demos on Meteor and I am extremely impressed.** But I know nothing of Mongo and I "think" Meteor requires it. (http://www.meteor.com/screencast)

I am too heavily invested in Entity Framework & ASP.net MVC to move away from them but Meteor looks like a terrific client side MV*.

Does anyone know if Meteor can work with a Microsoft back end (ie EF and ASP.net MVC)?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

Yes I see the NuGet package for MongoDb, but truth be told I am only interested in Meteor. Is it a both or nothing situation? Meteor looks like bleeding edge and I really would appreciate any links to documentation on its use with a MS backend.

Comment: Well, there are quite a few Mongo packages in NuGet, so I would assume it's possible...

Comment: you can check similar discussion on google group https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteorserver/A5irwJ-YQ7k[1-25]

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still reading this in 2013 or later - it's now possible to run Node.js on Windows under IIS (just install the support with the Web Platform Installer).

There's also versions of Meteor and MongoDB for Windows and Meteor supports deploying a bundle that will run under "pure" node.js

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, You can't. it runs over Node.js, additionally there is a client implementation of a MongoDB like API that would be a pain to implement with a EF backend I think

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of. Meteor runs server-side code using node.js, but also provides some very useful services on the client side like templates, routes, collections, session variables, and reactivity.

The way to use it with a .net back-end (or any other language) is to create an api that can be accessed with Meteor. You can create Meteor collections in the client code, which don't need a mongodb instance. Simply access the api to load the collections with the correct data, and then you can use Meteor as you would normally.

However, for most apps it would be much simpler to implement everything in Meteor.

Comment: Do you have a small example of how to do that as we are modifying all our WCF services to WebAPI and this would be great to use for several of our apps.